# Why do MinGW binaries have such complicated names? (e.g. i686-w64-mingw32-...)

Tags: mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

Looking at the mingw binaries presently on my system, I generally have `i686-w64-mingw32-*` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-*` commands.

I presume that the former compile 32-bit Windows executables, and the latter compile 64-bit Windows executables.

What, then, do `w64` and `mingw32` signify in the names of these binaries?

Would there be any meaning to a `w32` binary, e.g. `i686-w32-mingw32-gcc`?  I suppose `mingw32` is what it is because the project used to be called mingw32 and was renamed to MinGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW is based on [GCC](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc) and [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils), along with other GNU software. GNU projects use so-called "GNU triplets" to specify architecture information. A triplet has this format:

```
machine-vendor-operatingsystem
```

The triplet was specified when the binaries were built.

MinGW-w64 is using `w64` as the vendor field, and `mingw32` as the operating system. Of course, `mingw32` is not an operating system, but it is treated as one by the GCC and binutils build system and source code.

So these long names for the binaries are an artifact of the build system that GCC and binutils are using. All of these binaries are installed in the same directory, and so binaries that target different architectures (in this case 32-bit vs 64-bit) need to have different file names. The easiest way to do that is to prefix the binaries with the GNU triplet that describes those architectures.

Comment: just gave this answer an additional updoot, since it just significantly aided my understanding again today of how to cross-compile on linux for windows

Comment: @jcarpenter2 Since you mentioned cross compiling, have a look at this, in case you haven't discovered it yet: http://mxe.cc